# Every second Vuex commit to the same action is slow

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vuex V3.0.1 with Vue.js v 2.5.17

The same action commit in vuex is slow exactly every second time. If I put the same axios request inside my component and call it from within the component, it is consistently between 16 and 22 ms.  When I however dispatch to the store, every second request is consistently over 300ms.

[image: Chrome Network Traffic]

```
this.$store.dispatch('getQueryData', {QueryId: this.to.QueryId, params: data, CacheResults : this.to.CacheResults }).then(response => {
    this.options = response.data
        var arr = response.data
        var defaultValue = this.model[this.field.key] || this.field.defaultValue || null
        var valueprop = this.to.valueProp
        var model = {}
        if (defaultValue !== null)
        {
          this.options.forEach(function(value){
              if (value[valueprop] == defaultValue){
                model = value
              }
          })
          this.model[this.field.key] = model
        }
}, error => {
   this.$store.commit('setError', error.response)
   this.options = [];
})
```

And in my store

```
getQueryData ({commit}, payload) {
  const QueryIdStr = String(payload.QueryId)

  if (store.state.queries[QueryIdStr]) {
    var promise = Promise.resolve({data: store.state.queries[QueryIdStr]})
    return promise
  } else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .get('/scadservices/api/tablesv2/Query/' + payload.QueryId + '/data.json', {crossdomain: true, withCredentials: true, params: payload.params})
        .then(response => {
          var output = {
            QueryId: payload.QueryId,
            data: response.data
          }
          if (payload.CacheResults)
          {
            commit('setQueryData', output)
          }
          resolve(response)
        }, error => {
          commit('setError', error.response)
          reject(error)
        })
    })
  }
},
```

And in my mutations

```
setQueryData: (state, payload) => {
  const QueryIdStr = String(payload.QueryId)
  Vue.set(state.queries, QueryIdStr, payload.data)
}
```

Comment: Does this also happen when you call it the second time just in your component (without vuex)

Comment: Sorry, Only saw this now.  No, if I just use components it is consistently fast. It is just with vuex where each second call is slow