# Every Second axios call in Vuejs is slow

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

I am using Vuejs 2.6.11 with Vuex 3.2.0 and axios v0.19.2 and have a vary peculiar issue that I also reported on in this stackoverflow questions : [Every Second Vuex Commit to the same action is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715729/every-second-vuex-commit-to-the-same-action-is-slow)

I have eliminated the backend as not being the issue as I am calling the same backend endpoint from an Angular 1 app and other places with no issues with all calls being consistently fast after the first call.

I also tested the axios call without using vuex directly in the component, but I get exactly the same issue.

Below is the axios call in my local component.

```
 async getDataLocal() {
      // this.showCollapse = !this.showCollapse
      // this.$store.dispatch('getData', {TableId: this.TableId, ViewId: this.ViewId, PageNumber: this.PageNumber, PageSize: this.PageSize })
      await this.$axios
        .$get(
          '/scad/TablesV2/' +
            this.TableId +
            '/data?ViewId=' +
            this.ViewId +
            '&PageNumber=' +
            this.PageNumber +
            '&PageSize=' +
            this.PageSize
        )
        .then(
          response => {
            this.items = response
          },
          error => {
            reject(error)
          }
        )
    },
```

and here is the results from network traffic in Chrome. I did the calls about 1 second apart.

[image]

Below is the code for my vuex action.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let ParameterList = payload.ParameterList || {}
      vuexContext.commit('loading', true)
      this.$axios
        .$get(
          '/scad/tablesv2/' +
            payload.TableId +
            '/data.json?ViewId=' +
            payload.ViewId +
            '&PageNumber=' +
            payload.PageNumber +
            '&PageSize=' +
            payload.PageSize,
          {
            params: { ParameterList: payload.ParameterList },
            crossdomain: true,
            withCredentials: true
          }
        )
        .then(
          response => {
            const result = {
              TableId: payload.TableId,
              ViewId: payload.ViewId,
              PageNumber: payload.PageNumber,
              PageSize: payload.PageSize,
              data: response
            }
            vuexContext.commit('getData', result)
            resolve(result)
          },
          error => {
            vuexContext.commit('setError', error.response)
            reject(error)
          }
        )
      vuexContext.commit('loading', false)
    })
```

and here is the network traffic in Chrome to the same endpoint.  Again 1 second apart
[image]

and here is the network traffic to the same endpoint from an angular 1 app.

[image]

I searched the internet but was unable to find anything related.

Comment: literary having the exact same issue today. Sometimes when you refresh the page - you can navigate between the tabs 5-6 times and then suddenly every other call is slow.. until you refresh the page again. using `vuejs 3`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while working on a vue.js application with axios.

I found that the delay is due to using localhost in a Chromium-based browser on Windows OS. When viewing the details of each network request you can see that every second axios request is performing a DNS lookup.

If you replace localhost in your address bar with 127.0.0.1 the delay will be gone.

Comment: life-saver. Do you know if this is a `vuejs` specific issue since author does not have such problem with a `angularjs` app? Also, how do you know exactly that it's DNS issue? In network tab in request details I see that there is a `DNS` row on every second request but it only estimates 10ms at most.. How does this translates to 300ms delay exactly? **p.s. your advice worked anyways.**

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately I haven't looked into this any further than what's in my answer. Fair point about the 10ms DNS lookup. I don't know if DNS lookup is actually the cause of the delay. I suppose it was more of an observation that it occurs on the same requests which are slow. It is possible that something else is occurring on every-other request that is the culprit of the 300ms.

Comment: in my case in addition to DNS I also have a row named SSL (if I am not mistaken). It also appears every second call. Therefore this issue might be related to encryption as well. I am not sure if that is the case. I have recently switched to HTTPS protocol with self-generated self-signed local certificate for local development :) Anyways I think this is one of those complex problems when nobody wants to spend their time on, once it's fixed :D thank you again for help! Hopefully somebody from vuejs team will pick this topic up later.